# Flutter NestedScrollView/SliverAppBar - unwanted bottom margin

Tags: dart, flutter, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, margins

To build appbar with Navigation Drawer:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var drawerOptions = <Widget>[];
    for (var i = 0; i < widget.drawerItems.length; i++) {
      var d = widget.drawerItems[i];
      drawerOptions.add(new ListTile(
        leading: new Icon(d.icon),
        title: new Text(d.title),
        selected: i == _selectedDrawerIndex,
        onTap: () => _onSelectItem(i),
      ));
    }
    drawerOptions.add(
        new RaisedButton(onPressed: () => {}, child: new Text("Ustawienia")));

    return new Scaffold(
        body: NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                expandedHeight: 130.0,
                floating: false,
                pinned: true,
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  title:
                      new Text(widget.drawerItems[_selectedDrawerIndex].title),
                ),
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: _getDrawerItemWidget(_selectedDrawerIndex),
        ),
        drawer: new Drawer(
          child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                  accountName: new Text("Gość"), accountEmail: null),
              new Column(children: drawerOptions)
            ],
          ),
        ));
```

Result:

[image]

So there is unwanted white margin just above body. If I try with regular appbar, this way:

```
return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        // here we display the title corresponding to the fragment
        // you can instead choose to have a static title
        title: new Text(widget.drawerItems[_selectedDrawerIndex].title),
      ),
      drawer: new Drawer(
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                accountName: new Text("Gość"), accountEmail: null),
            new Column(children: drawerOptions)
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: _getDrawerItemWidget(_selectedDrawerIndex),
    );
```

Result is fine, no any extra margin:

[image]

How to remove unwanted extra margin and align title to left in expanded mode (it should be placed under hamburger menu indicator).

`DrawerItem` class definition:

```
class DrawerItem {
  String title;
  IconData icon;

  DrawerItem(this.title, this.icon);
}
```

`drawerItems` is defined as follows:

```
final drawerItems = [
    new DrawerItem("Option1", Icons.list),
    new DrawerItem("Option2", Icons.event_note),
    new DrawerItem("Option3", Icons.account_balance),
   //... etc
  ];
```

Comment: Have you tried reducing the expanded height? If you set to a constant value (such as 130.0) it will always use that space when fully expanded.

Comment: Expanded height does not matter. It only sets how much I can expand. When expanded, alwyas extra white space is there.

Comment: I see, but if your header is only 100 pixels, the remaining 30.0 will be an empty space when fully expanded. Is this happening even with less expanded height?

Comment: Yes, extra space is there even when less expeanded, when scrolling list up, expand decreasing (as it should) with stick white unwanted margin as on screenshoot. When toolbar is fully collapsed and I keep scrolling list, white space can be hidden and after that I can scroll list itself to see next items

Comment: Have you tried to set the `ListTile` content padding property to zero?

Comment: `ListTile` is menu item for navigation drawer, it has nothing to do with toolbar. Even if I set it to 0, it obviously does not change anything (except menu items are wrong aligned)

Comment: It’s not quite clear how you’re constructing the header and the content because you’re calling it from somewhere else (drawerItems).

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was facing the same issue with a nested scroll view. I was using a grid view as body and setting its padding to 0 got rid of the space

```
GridView.builder(
   padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
```

so whatever widgets you are returnign from this method `_getDrawerItemWidget(_selectedDrawerIndex)`, try adding padding to it.

Answer (score 9):

```
Widget _getDrawerItemWidget(){
  return MediaQuery.removePadding(
    context: context,
    removeTop: true,
    child: ListView.builder(
     .......
    )
  );
}
```

more information : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14842